# FB Open Graph: why when my app posts an action on user's wall, action link related to the action is not shown on the post?

Tags: facebook, action, facebook-opengraph, actionlink

I have defined and got approved by the Facebook the following actions in my app:

1) Donate to

2) Share

which have connected objects Video and Article.

Both of the actions have linked action 'Donate to', i.e. when user donates in my app to some video, the post gets printed on his wall and this post should contain an action link 'Donate to this video' right after the usual "Like * Comment * Share" stuff.

For the last month or two, without changing a line in my own code, I noticed the following when my app posting on user's wall:

1) Month ago, as a user who made a donation, I was able to see 'Donate to' action link, but now I can't, only my friends can.

2) Sometimes, action link fails to appear at all, neither user, who made a donation, nor his friends are able to see it.

Does somebody observed similar behavior? Could it be improved somehow?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug at the moment. You can follow the bug on facebook at:

`https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/457578704276661`